# how to show product sku in custom admin grid in magento2

Tags: magento2

hello everyone I have the product_id store in my database through it I want to display product SKU in admin grid, product name I showing in it

n ui_component i have

> index.xml

`<column name="entity_id" class="Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products">
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> 
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
 <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products name</item> </item> </argument> </column> </columns>`

Comment: how is the collection retrieved for your grid?

Comment: through database

Comment: you should post some code.

Comment: which file code you want?

Comment: The code that retrieves the data from the database to list in your grid

Comment: in ui_component i have index.xml
   <column name="entity_id" class="Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products"> 
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array"> 
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array"> 
   <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products name</item> 
   </item> 
   </argument> 
   </column>
 </columns> through this code product name is coming